# Angular multiple form values in ngFor

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

hope somebody can help me? I'm building a form in my component like this (Version not running):

```
<div *ngFor="let status of someService.monitoringStatus">
 <form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="updateStatus(form.value,status.id)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="next_status" value="{{status.old_status}}">
 </form>
</div>
```

The problem now is that I can't get {{status.old_status}} in my input as value. But why? If I am using it outside it shows me right.

Edit (my component.ts looks like this):

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    next_status: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  })


  updateStatus(value,id: any){
    this.someService.updateStatus(value,id).toPromise().then((data: any) => {  console.log(data)
    }).catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.error('Fehler:', err.error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why is the `form` element inside the `*ngFor` loop? You are creating as many `form` elements as the `status` count.

Comment: That is right. I need solution to send forms based of ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

So you have your forms inside an `*ngFor` - but they all have the same name, so how can the code distinguish between them?  They must all have unique names. If you add an index, you can give them unique names

```
<div *ngFor="let status of someService.monitoringStatus; let i=index;">
 <form name="form{{i}}" [formGroup]="form{{i}}" (ngSubmit)="updateStatus(form{{i}}.value,status.id)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="next_status{{i}}" value="{{status.old_status}}">
 </form>
</div>
```

Then you can use `{{i}}` to distinguish them from each other

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply my question. I thought about this solution before. But how does my component.ts has to look like with  form = new FormGroup({ .... ??

Comment: declare your forms as form0, form1,...
If you include you ts code, I could help you with syntax based on what you have

Comment: where do you get `someService.monitoringStatus` from? Is it an array? What is its type? In theory, you can make an array of forms, then if `someService.monitoringStatus` gives an array, run a `foreach` on it where you add another new form to the array. And then in HTML, `forms[i]` instead of `form{{i}}`

Comment: I created a repo which describes problem perfectly. https://github.com/sascha284/forms

Comment: the link is broken